# What factors determine the video quality and audio quality of a laptop's HDMI output signal?

Tags: audio, hdmi, hardware-rec

This is more or less asking what do I need to do to maximize the quality of an output HDMI signal? What computer/hardware has the best HDMI output? I find my Mac laptop has better video output than a cheap Chromebook. Is it graphics card?

Comment: Buy a better laptop with a better graphics chip.

Comment: If the card is a digital card such as HDMI, then the factor is the video card. If you are using VGA, then cable might factor it. But nowadays HDMI is all based on the system’s digital signal.